# Retrieve Window Handle and Press Button Programatically

Tags: c#

I'm sure this is possible somehow, but not sure if there are a few too many hoops to jump through to make it worthwhile, hoping someone might point me in the right direction. I've got a problem (related to an installer) whereby I have a dialog popup quite regularly which I need to press cancel on.

What I'd like to do is close it programatically/maybe via a service so it stops getting in my way (assuming I can't fix the root issue). So, what I'm wondering is if there is a way to grab a handle to the window somehow (checking it's correct maybe by doing a text comparison on the label), then locating a control on the window (cancel button) and sending an event to it?

If anyone knows how I might achieve this or some starters that'd be great.

Comment: I suspect this is going to be way more trouble than fixing the issue that's causing the dialog to pop-up, trouble both during the install and after it. After all, there has to be a good reason for a modal dialog popping up.

Comment: Indeed, it might well be and I'll probably be posting about that too. But this approach also helps improve my development skills and just seems way more fun! :)

Comment: see http://www.autohotkey.com/, with source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways to do this:

- To get the handle, when you talk about a window, use the [FindWindow](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/FindWindow.html) API, then you would have to enumerate the controls associated with that handle, and send a message WM_BUTTONDOWN, WM_BUTTONUP together to simulate a mouse click via using a [SendMessage](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SendMessage.html).
- But the simpler method exists, suppose the cancel button is called `btnCancel`, then this would suffice `btnCancel.Click()`.

Unless I am mistaken, that you are talking about a window of a process that is not yours, then my first suggestion would do. Since you did not say, if you are talking about your own application or a process's window that is not yours...then Oliver's suggestion might be easier...

But that begs the question: why would you want to do that as you are assuming there is a Cancel button somewhere...

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into [AutoIt3](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/). It can do such casts quite easy and if you dig a little deeper into it, you'll find out which WindowsAPI calls it uses to do its stuff. These APIs you can then PInvoke in C# if you really need it there. Otherwise just write an AutoIt script to perform your task.